# MsgBox doesn't display the zero added in cell using the custom format

Tags: excel, vba

I'm generating numbers and having a msgbox display the number generated.

The problem is, my number has to begin with 0.

But Excel kept on deleting the 0 so I used the custom format cell to always display a 0 in front of my numbers `0000#`

But now, when it generate the number, the msg box doesnt display the 0.

here is a part of my code :

```
cell_value = Sheet1.Cells(4, "A").Value & Sheet1.Cells(4, "B").Value & Sheet1.Cells(4, "C").Value
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
        MsgBox ("The number is : " & cell_value)
    End If
```

Comment: Use `Format$`...

Comment: @BigBen I dont know what `Format$` is ... how and where to use?

Comment: What cell has the formatting - A or B or C or all of them?

Comment: @BigBen B range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom number formats don't change the underlying value of the cell.

If you need the custom format, use `Format$`, e.g.

```
cell_value = Sheet1.Cells(4, "A").Value & _
             Format$(Sheet1.Cells(4, "B").Value, "0000#") & _
             Sheet1.Cells(4, "C").Value
```